# Extracting statistical parameters from a mixture of two distributions of different kind

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, mixture-distribution

I have a dataset `b` (as a list in Python) of length 100 I know that is amounts to the mixture of two distributions:

- A normal distribution
- A uniform distribution

See:[image]

I would like to extract the

- variance `sigma`
- mixture weights (two numbers between 0 and 1 that describe the contribution of each distribution) `[w_1,w_2]`

of this mixture. Were I given a mixture of normal distributions I could use something like EM algorithm.

**How can I extract these parameters for such a mixture?**

For completeness I am attaching the data:

```
b =[1.654296875, 2.51171875, 2.650390625, 2.734375, 2.62109375, 2.9140625, 2.43359375, 2.1484375, 3.07421875, 3.060546875, 3.033203125, 3.212890625, 2.484375, 2.921875, 2.62109375, 3.34375, 1.76953125, 1.94921875, 1.677734375, 2.544921875, 2.146484375, 2.513671875, 2.943359375, 3.328125, 3.248046875, 2.84375, 3.53125, 2.3984375, 3.2109375, 3.466796875, 1.658203125, 1.96875, 2.994140625, 3.140625, 3.109375, 1.92578125, 1.751953125, 3.41015625, 2.888671875, 2.216796875, 3.146484375, 2.51953125, 3.41015625, 2.48828125, 2.51953125, 2.384765625, 3.22265625, 2.990234375, 3.306640625, 3.453125, 2.212890625, 2.99609375, 3.095703125, 3.2890625, 3.341796875, 2.94921875, 3.158203125, 3.4296875, 2.962890625, 2.5234375, 1.74609375, 2.09765625, 2.861328125, 3.4609375, 2.103515625, 1.712890625, 1.7265625, 3.255859375, 3.357421875, 3.0, 1.68359375, 2.419921875, 3.009765625, 2.90234375, 2.748046875, 3.197265625, 2.78515625, 2.3671875, 2.955078125, 3.5234375, 2.458984375, 2.498046875, 2.564453125, 3.0, 3.236328125, 2.7109375, 3.201171875, 2.103515625, 3.08984375, 1.986328125, 2.73828125, 3.09375, 3.48828125, 3.189453125, 3.134765625, 3.00390625, 2.765625, 2.982421875, 2.5234375, 1.630859375, 2.92578125, 3.255859375, 3.212890625, 2.53125, 2.869140625, 2.904296875, 3.177734375, 2.830078125, 2.48828125, 2.95703125, 2.962890625, 2.64453125, 3.083984375, 3.373046875, 2.119140625, 2.958984375, 3.111328125, 2.025390625, 3.078125, 1.8203125, 2.658203125, 2.29296875, 2.66796875, 2.990234375, 2.998046875, 3.25390625, 2.146484375, 3.001953125, 2.73828125, 2.72265625, 2.580078125, 2.109375, 2.7890625, 2.646484375, 3.521484375, 3.126953125, 2.974609375, 2.921875, 2.13671875, 3.3046875, 2.5234375, 2.7890625, 3.3203125, 2.85546875, 3.05078125, 3.279296875, 3.05859375, 3.521484375, 2.9765625, 2.31640625, 3.154296875, 3.109375, 1.869140625, 3.1171875, 3.029296875, 2.41796875, 2.49609375, 3.419921875, 2.96484375, 2.669921875, 3.021484375, 2.642578125, 2.791015625, 2.62890625, 3.16015625, 2.40625, 2.66796875, 2.552734375, 2.1171875, 2.96875, 3.328125, 2.763671875, 2.3828125, 2.53125, 2.712890625, 2.97265625, 2.478515625, 2.87890625, 3.193359375, 3.341796875, 2.8984375, 3.0859375, 2.724609375, 2.703125, 2.74609375, 2.828125, 2.8671875, 2.705078125, 3.109375, 2.748046875, 2.90625, 2.76171875, 2.564453125, 2.978515625, 3.30078125, 2.705078125, 2.53515625, 2.3984375, 2.76171875, 2.740234375, 2.98828125, 3.0234375, 2.23828125, 2.97265625, 2.447265625, 1.59765625, 2.509765625, 1.978515625, 2.025390625, 3.130859375, 3.4375, 2.740234375, 3.396484375, 3.017578125, 3.521484375, 3.111328125, 1.998046875, 3.275390625, 3.18359375, 2.28125, 3.22265625, 1.771484375, 2.9375, 2.455078125, 2.0859375, 2.23046875, 2.71484375, 2.6484375, 2.82421875, 2.8984375, 3.322265625, 3.068359375, 3.05859375, 2.77734375, 2.03125, 2.908203125, 3.234375, 2.728515625, 1.619140625, 2.69140625, 2.8671875, 2.9765625, 3.50390625, 2.73046875, 3.208984375, 2.779296875, 2.873046875, 2.556640625, 2.65625, 3.275390625, 3.263671875, 2.138671875, 3.521484375, 3.37109375, 2.849609375, 2.484375, 2.62109375, 3.16796875, 1.904296875, 2.576171875, 2.244140625, 3.037109375, 2.32421875, 2.009765625, 3.23046875, 2.537109375, 2.943359375, 2.947265625, 3.46484375, 2.10546875, 2.9296875, 3.353515625, 2.240234375, 2.9140625, 2.04296875, 2.96484375, 2.93359375, 2.18359375, 2.39453125, 2.521484375, 2.724609375, 2.67578125, 1.634765625, 2.083984375, 1.6796875, 2.423828125, 3.41015625, 2.49609375, 2.705078125, 2.90234375, 2.4765625, 2.93359375, 2.95703125, 3.0078125, 1.9765625, 3.15234375, 2.5390625, 3.484375, 2.98046875, 2.572265625, 2.50390625, 3.23046875, 2.49609375, 1.693359375, 2.1640625, 2.990234375, 2.0703125, 2.982421875, 2.04296875, 1.701171875, 2.955078125, 2.41015625, 3.529296875, 2.4609375, 2.177734375, 2.59375, 2.921875, 2.265625, 1.974609375, 2.51953125, 2.59375, 2.79296875, 2.724609375, 2.376953125, 2.287109375, 1.8828125, 3.38671875, 3.1015625, 3.26171875, 2.4609375, 2.447265625, 2.3125, 2.791015625, 3.28125, 2.931640625, 2.736328125, 3.337890625, 2.091796875, 1.986328125, 2.26953125, 2.923828125, 2.6640625, 3.189453125, 2.62109375, 2.587890625, 2.548828125, 2.552734375, 2.517578125, 3.40234375, 1.873046875, 3.197265625, 2.705078125, 2.140625, 2.77734375, 2.7109375, 3.1015625, 2.830078125, 3.208984375, 3.099609375, 2.4609375, 2.80859375, 1.578125, 2.970703125, 2.6796875, 2.498046875, 2.783203125, 2.458984375, 2.58984375, 2.041015625, 3.142578125, 2.501953125, 2.541015625, 2.69921875, 3.44140625, 3.232421875, 3.123046875, 1.65234375, 3.048828125, 3.171875, 2.921875, 2.11328125, 3.23046875, 2.501953125, 3.19140625, 2.677734375, 2.958984375, 2.81640625, 3.23828125, 3.166015625, 2.59765625, 2.8671875, 2.77734375, 2.1796875, 1.763671875, 2.32421875, 3.408203125, 1.90234375, 2.59375, 1.630859375, 3.431640625, 2.515625, 2.888671875, 3.2578125, 2.1875, 2.978515625, 1.7578125, 3.0546875, 3.193359375, 2.48828125, 2.73046875, 2.77734375, 2.8046875, 3.138671875, 3.369140625, 3.361328125, 2.400390625, 2.921875, 2.947265625, 2.833984375, 2.4609375, 3.2265625, 2.751953125, 2.5625, 3.08203125, 2.720703125, 1.888671875, 3.21875, 2.04296875, 3.451171875, 2.705078125, 2.568359375, 1.75390625, 3.37890625, 3.234375, 2.17578125, 2.580078125, 2.556640625, 2.90234375, 2.95703125, 3.041015625, 2.666015625, 2.740234375, 2.564453125, 2.58203125, 2.76953125, 3.28515625, 2.341796875, 2.4921875, 3.06640625, 2.76953125, 1.896484375, 2.826171875, 2.80078125, 3.51171875, 2.53125, 1.943359375, 2.5234375, 3.23046875, 3.109375, 2.75390625, 2.517578125, 3.177734375, 2.982421875, 2.095703125, 2.365234375, 2.4921875, 1.9765625, 3.08203125, 2.62890625, 3.51953125, 3.474609375, 2.546875, 1.69140625, 2.84765625, 3.482421875, 1.61328125, 2.490234375, 2.96484375, 2.966796875, 3.05078125, 2.62890625, 1.84765625, 3.330078125, 2.482421875, 2.84375, 1.67578125, 1.958984375, 2.001953125, 3.017578125, 2.259765625, 3.12890625, 2.70703125, 3.435546875, 2.859375, 3.03125, 3.025390625, 3.208984375, 2.77734375, 2.109375, 1.654296875, 2.51171875, 2.650390625, 2.734375, 2.62109375, 2.9140625, 2.43359375, 2.1484375, 3.07421875, 3.060546875, 3.033203125, 3.212890625, 2.484375, 2.921875, 2.62109375, 3.34375, 1.76953125, 1.94921875, 1.677734375, 2.544921875, 2.146484375, 2.513671875, 2.943359375, 3.328125, 3.248046875, 2.84375, 3.53125, 2.3984375, 3.2109375, 3.466796875, 1.658203125, 1.96875, 2.994140625, 3.140625, 3.109375, 1.92578125, 1.751953125, 3.41015625, 2.888671875, 2.216796875, 3.146484375, 2.51953125, 3.41015625, 2.48828125, 2.51953125, 2.384765625, 3.22265625, 2.990234375, 3.306640625, 3.453125, 2.212890625, 2.99609375, 3.095703125, 3.2890625, 3.341796875, 2.94921875, 3.158203125, 3.4296875, 2.962890625, 2.5234375, 1.74609375, 2.09765625, 2.861328125, 3.4609375, 2.103515625, 1.712890625, 1.7265625, 3.255859375, 3.357421875, 3.0, 1.68359375, 2.419921875, 3.009765625, 2.90234375, 2.748046875, 3.197265625, 2.78515625, 2.3671875, 2.955078125, 3.5234375, 2.458984375, 2.498046875, 2.564453125, 3.0, 3.236328125, 2.7109375, 3.201171875, 2.103515625, 3.08984375, 1.986328125, 2.73828125, 3.09375, 3.48828125, 3.189453125, 3.134765625, 3.00390625, 2.765625, 2.982421875, 2.5234375, 1.630859375, 2.92578125, 3.255859375, 3.212890625, 2.53125, 2.869140625, 2.904296875, 3.177734375, 2.830078125, 2.48828125, 2.95703125, 2.962890625, 2.64453125, 3.083984375, 3.373046875, 2.119140625, 2.958984375, 3.111328125, 2.025390625, 3.078125, 1.8203125, 2.658203125, 2.29296875, 2.66796875, 2.990234375, 2.998046875, 3.25390625, 2.146484375, 3.001953125, 2.73828125, 2.72265625, 2.580078125, 2.109375, 2.7890625, 2.646484375, 3.521484375, 3.126953125, 2.974609375, 2.921875, 2.13671875, 3.3046875, 2.5234375, 2.7890625, 3.3203125, 2.85546875, 3.05078125, 3.279296875, 3.05859375, 3.521484375, 2.9765625, 2.31640625, 3.154296875, 3.109375, 1.869140625, 3.1171875, 3.029296875, 2.41796875, 2.49609375, 3.419921875, 2.96484375, 2.669921875, 3.021484375, 2.642578125, 2.791015625, 2.62890625, 3.16015625, 2.40625, 2.66796875, 2.552734375, 2.1171875, 2.96875, 3.328125, 2.763671875, 2.3828125, 2.53125, 2.712890625, 2.97265625, 2.478515625, 2.87890625, 3.193359375, 3.341796875, 2.8984375, 3.0859375, 2.724609375, 2.703125, 2.74609375, 2.828125, 2.8671875, 2.705078125, 3.109375, 2.748046875, 2.90625, 2.76171875, 2.564453125, 2.978515625, 3.30078125, 2.705078125, 2.53515625, 2.3984375, 2.76171875, 2.740234375, 2.98828125, 3.0234375, 2.23828125, 2.97265625, 2.447265625, 1.59765625, 2.509765625, 1.978515625, 2.025390625, 3.130859375, 3.4375, 2.740234375, 3.396484375, 3.017578125, 3.521484375, 3.111328125, 1.998046875, 3.275390625, 3.18359375, 2.28125, 3.22265625, 1.771484375, 2.9375, 2.455078125, 2.0859375, 2.23046875, 2.71484375, 2.6484375, 2.82421875, 2.8984375, 3.322265625, 3.068359375, 3.05859375, 2.77734375, 2.03125, 2.908203125, 3.234375, 2.728515625, 1.619140625, 2.69140625, 2.8671875, 2.9765625, 3.50390625, 2.73046875, 3.208984375, 2.779296875, 2.873046875, 2.556640625, 2.65625, 3.275390625, 3.263671875, 2.138671875, 3.521484375, 3.37109375, 2.849609375, 2.484375, 2.62109375, 3.16796875, 1.904296875, 2.576171875, 2.244140625, 3.037109375, 2.32421875, 2.009765625, 3.23046875, 2.537109375, 2.943359375, 2.947265625, 3.46484375, 2.10546875, 2.9296875, 3.353515625, 2.240234375, 2.9140625, 2.04296875, 2.96484375, 2.93359375, 2.18359375, 2.39453125, 2.521484375, 2.724609375, 2.67578125, 1.634765625, 2.083984375, 1.6796875, 2.423828125, 3.41015625, 2.49609375, 2.705078125, 2.90234375, 2.4765625, 2.93359375, 2.95703125, 3.0078125, 1.9765625, 3.15234375, 2.5390625, 3.484375, 2.98046875, 2.572265625, 2.50390625, 3.23046875, 2.49609375, 1.693359375, 2.1640625, 2.990234375, 2.0703125, 2.982421875, 2.04296875, 1.701171875, 2.955078125, 2.41015625, 3.529296875, 2.4609375, 2.177734375, 2.59375, 2.921875, 2.265625, 1.974609375, 2.51953125, 2.59375, 2.79296875, 2.724609375, 2.376953125, 2.287109375, 1.8828125, 3.38671875, 3.1015625, 3.26171875, 2.4609375, 2.447265625, 2.3125, 2.791015625, 3.28125, 2.931640625, 2.736328125, 3.337890625, 2.091796875, 1.986328125, 2.26953125, 2.923828125, 2.6640625, 3.189453125, 2.62109375, 2.587890625, 2.548828125, 2.552734375, 2.517578125, 3.40234375, 1.873046875, 3.197265625, 2.705078125, 2.140625, 2.77734375, 2.7109375, 3.1015625, 2.830078125, 3.208984375, 3.099609375, 2.4609375, 2.80859375, 1.578125, 2.970703125, 2.6796875, 2.498046875, 2.783203125, 2.458984375, 2.58984375, 2.041015625, 3.142578125, 2.501953125, 2.541015625, 2.69921875, 3.44140625, 3.232421875, 3.123046875, 1.65234375, 3.048828125, 3.171875, 2.921875, 2.11328125, 3.23046875, 2.501953125, 3.19140625, 2.677734375, 2.958984375, 2.81640625, 3.23828125, 3.166015625, 2.59765625, 2.8671875, 2.77734375, 2.1796875, 1.763671875, 2.32421875, 3.408203125, 1.90234375, 2.59375, 1.630859375, 3.431640625, 2.515625, 2.888671875, 3.2578125, 2.1875, 2.978515625, 1.7578125, 3.0546875, 3.193359375, 2.48828125, 2.73046875, 2.77734375, 2.8046875, 3.138671875, 3.369140625, 3.361328125, 2.400390625, 2.921875, 2.947265625, 2.833984375, 2.4609375, 3.2265625, 2.751953125, 2.5625, 3.08203125, 2.720703125, 1.888671875, 3.21875, 2.04296875, 3.451171875, 2.705078125, 2.568359375, 1.75390625, 3.37890625, 3.234375, 2.17578125, 2.580078125, 2.556640625, 2.90234375, 2.95703125, 3.041015625, 2.666015625, 2.740234375, 2.564453125, 2.58203125, 2.76953125, 3.28515625, 2.341796875, 2.4921875, 3.06640625, 2.76953125, 1.896484375, 2.826171875, 2.80078125, 3.51171875, 2.53125, 1.943359375, 2.5234375, 3.23046875, 3.109375, 2.75390625, 2.517578125, 3.177734375, 2.982421875, 2.095703125, 2.365234375, 2.4921875, 1.9765625, 3.08203125, 2.62890625, 3.51953125, 3.474609375, 2.546875, 1.69140625, 2.84765625, 3.482421875, 1.61328125, 2.490234375, 2.96484375, 2.966796875, 3.05078125, 2.62890625, 1.84765625, 3.330078125, 2.482421875, 2.84375, 1.67578125, 1.958984375, 2.001953125, 3.017578125, 2.259765625, 3.12890625, 2.70703125, 3.435546875, 2.859375, 3.03125, 3.025390625, 3.208984375, 2.77734375, 2.109375]
```

Comment: Not sure. I am following this thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173404/modeling-a-mixture-of-a-gaussian-and-uniform-matlab and I cannot get any good results.

Comment: This answer does not use EM. Try to replicate the EM solution for a mixture of two normals into the EM solution for a mixture of Normal and Uniform, given that the latent variable representation is the same.

Comment: However, that answer implements MLE which is claimed by the OP to work well.

Comment: If this histogram reflects your data, then it would be better to adopt a different model.  The abrupt cutoff at the right provides a good estimate of the uniform component, but the large discrepancy between heights at the left and heights at the right shows that approximating this component as uniform will be poor.

Answer (score 3):

In case the mixture density you want to estimate writes as
$$\omega_1 \underbrace{\varphi(x;\mu,\sigma)}_\text{normal pdf}+\omega_2(\theta_2-\theta_1)^{-1}\mathbb I_{[\theta_1,\theta_2]}(x)
\qquad\text{with}\qquad\omega_1+\omega_2=1,\,\sigma>0,\,\theta_2>\theta_1$$
the complete likelihood used for EM writes down as
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \omega_1^{z_i}\varphi(x_i;\mu,\sigma)^{z_i}\omega_2^{1-z_i}
(\theta_2-\theta_1)^{z_i-1}\mathbb I^{1-z_i}_{[\theta_1,\theta_2]}(x_i)\qquad z_i\in\{0,1\}$$
or
$$\prod_{i;x_i\notin[\theta_1,\theta_2]}\omega_1\varphi(x_i;\mu,\sigma)
\times\prod_{i;x_i\in[\theta_1,\theta_2]}\omega_1^{z_i}\varphi(x_i;\mu,\sigma)^{z_i}\omega_2^{1-z_i}(\theta_2-\theta_1)^{z_i-1}$$
The E function is therefore, when the current value of the parameter is $\xi_0=(\mu^0,\sigma^0,\theta_1^0,\theta_2^0,\omega_1^0,\omega_2^0)$, equal to
$$E[\xi|\xi^0) = \sum_{i;x_i\notin[\theta_1,\theta_2]}[\log(\omega_1)+\log\varphi(x_i;\mu,\sigma)]\\+\sum_{i;x_i\in[\theta_1,\theta_2]}\{[\log (\omega_1)+\log
\varphi(x_i;\mu,\sigma)]\mathbb E_{\xi_0}[Z_i|x_i]\\+\
[\log\{\omega_2/(\theta_2-\theta_1)\}]\mathbb E_{\xi_0}[1-Z_i|x_i]\}$$
Here
$$\mathbb E_{\xi_0}[Z_i|x_i]=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } x_i\notin[\theta_1^0,\theta_2^0]\\
{\omega_1^0 \varphi(x_i;\mu^0,\sigma^0)}\big/{\omega_1^0 \varphi(x_i;\mu^0,\sigma^0)+\omega_2^0/(\theta_2^0-\theta_1^0)} &\text{if } x_i\in[\theta_1^0,\theta_2^0]
\end{cases}$$
The M-step corresponds to the optimisation of $E[\xi|\xi^0)$ in $\xi$. (Note that $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are necessarily equal to one of the observations.)